# How do I use OpenVZ 7 hardware node for name service caching with *all* container types?

Tags: dns, cache, openvz

I've stopped using OpenVZ for a couple of years and now I'm back at it I feel somewhat overwhelmed by the increased level of complexity. I'm just stuck for hours on this simple task:

I want to use the hardware node as my local DNS cache for *all* container types (which paradigm is new to me), host and bridged.

I have only containers.

I have successfully configured `dnsmasq` to listen on both `br0` and `virbr0`, the interfaces for bridged and host-only containers, respectively. I could confirm the step with `dig @interface <public host name>` and that works.

What doesn't work:

- name resolution in any container times out
- pinging the hardware node address gives no reply

From the hardware node:

```
# prlsrvctl net list
Network ID        Type      Bound To       Bridge         Slave interfaces
Bridged           bridged   enp2s0         br0                           
Host-Only         host-only                virbr0
```

With `virbr0: 10.37.130.2/24` and `br0:192.168.xx.5/28`.

I've run `prlctl set <my test container @ 192.168.xx.4> --nameserver 10.37.130.2` and even though it has no name resolution.

I *suppose* I need to add a rule to `iptables` but, man, there are so many even for local processes! Even common sense doesn't help: I've tried adding a rule to accept UDP packets on port 53 for both interfaces... no way, there's something else.

Just don't know what to hack:

- I don't know if `dnsmasq` receives the DNS requests
- I don't know if it sends responses
- I don't know if the responses are blocked by the firewall.

Here's what I have with `tcpdump`, whether I add my firewall rule or not:

```
# tcpdump
tcpdump: WARNING: venet0: no IPv4 address assigned
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on venet0, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 65535 bytes
23:03:20.876113 IP 192.168.xx.4.53894 > myhostname.local.domain: 32621+ A? google.com. (28)
23:03:25.875974 IP 192.168.xx.4.53894 > myhostname.local.domain: 32621+ A? google.com. (28)
^C
2 packets captured
2 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

This happens when I do a simple `host google.com` from a container that has the `host` command.

From that container:

```
# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=39 time=328 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=39 time=19.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=39 time=20.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=39 time=20.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=39 time=44.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=39 time=20.4 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 19.836/75.699/328.996/113.614 ms
```

Then why the ... does the firewall list these rules?

```
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Frustratingly complicated.